# Best way to update progress bar from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, progress-bar

I've got a long-running task that is executed in a thread.

The code for this all takes place in a separate class than the `WinMain()` entry point, say `WorkerClass`.

I'd like to update a progress bar every so often with the progress of the task.

After several hours of research, trial, and error, I've come across several methods:

---

A) Custom `PostMessage` to main window proc from inside the thread *(problem: frowned upon by several sources: thread should not touch main UI)*

B) Custom `PostMessage` to main window proc from some `WorkerClass` function *(problem: running into scope issues between free vs class functions, since thread function has to be free of class)*

C) Worker thread updates `int` pointer, then a UI-thread timer updates UI periodically *(problem: worth spending time on, or is this "doing it wrong")*

---

A lot of the discussion dives into MFC or C# which I'm not interested in.

I'm to the point where I've run into roadblocks with all three methods. It will be several hours to do a good job on figuring one out - I don't want to put in effort learning it wrong.

Which one should I pursue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW: The code base I currently work on posts a message to the main thread.

Another method, and the one I prefer, is the Observer Pattern.  The main thread would "subscribe" to the worker and whenever the worker updates itself, it notifies its observers (any object that subscribed to it).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: OK so it sounds like that code base uses `A` but you prefer `B`?

Comment: I prefer where the main thread registers with the worker thread.  Then when the worker threads updates its progress, its "UpdateProgress()" function iterates through all subscribers and calls their "ProgressUpdated()" function - a callback essentially.

Comment: Thanks, combined with my next question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506377/trouble-referencing-class-in-structure-using-this-keyword#13506421) I've got stuff working pretty well now.