# Trouble referencing class in structure using this keyword

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, struct

Header file:

```
// Free function to use in thread
unsigned int __stdcall WorkerFunction(void *);

class MyClass {
    public:
        int temp;
        void StartThread();
}

typedef struct {
    MyClass * cls;
} DATA;
```

CPP class:

```
void MyClass::StartThread() {
    temp = 1234;
    DATA data = {this};

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(0, 0, &WorkerFunction, &data, 0, 0);

    // Commented out for now while I address the current problem
    //CloseHandle(hThread);
}

unsigned int __stdcall WorkerFunction(void * param0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "WorkerFunction()", "Alert", MB_OK);
    DATA * data = (DATA *) param0;
    MyClass* cls0 = data->cls;

    // Crashes when reference to cls0 is attempted.
    char buf[5];
    snprintf(buf, 5, "%i", cls0 ->temp);
    MessageBox(NULL, buf, "Alert", MB_OK);
}
```

I've got an easy problem here that I can't put my finger on.

- I have params for a thread, which pass a struct which contains a class.
- I instantiate the struct with `this` and then pass it when the thread starts
- I try to dereference (?) it in the worker function.
- At this point, everything compiles OK.
- When I add lines to access something in the class, the app crashes.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a local stack variable that is out-of-scope the moment `StartThread()` returns. You are therefore referencing stack-space that no longer belongs to you.

```
void MyClass::StartThread() {
    temp = 1234;
    DATA data = {this}; // << LOCAL VARIABLE OUT OF SCOPE ON FUNCTION EXIT

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(0, 0, &WorkerFunction, &data, 0, 0);

    // Commented out for now while I address the current problem
    //CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Either dynamically allocate the data, or better still, make the data a member of `MyClass` and pass `this` as the thread data. In your case you're only passing *this anyway through a struct, so just pass it as the param

```
void MyClass::StartThread() {
    temp = 1234;

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(0, 0, &WorkerFunction, this, 0, 0);

    // Commented out for now while I address the current problem
    //CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

And in your thread proc:

```
unsigned int __stdcall WorkerFunction(void * param0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "WorkerFunction()", "Alert", MB_OK);
    MyClass* cls0 = static_cast<MyClass*>(param0);

   etc...
}
```

Whatever you pass to your thread procedure, it must have valid lifetime for the duration required. by the thread. Either ensure that by passing ownership of a dynamic allocation to the thread at let *it* do the delete, or pass a pointer known hold determinate state for the lifetime of its usage in the thread-proc. It appears `this` fulfills the latter, so you should likely be good to go.

Comment: Dammit scope gets me every time.  Any suggestion on how to fix?

Comment: Cheers, I've got a couple of my own but they're probably barking up the wrong tree...only I find out after I've left the forest :)

Comment: And we have liftoff.  Thanks very much.  That's about a million times more awesome than my pathetic little piles of junky code heheh.

Comment: @Steve no problem. Just make sure if you use the suggestion that your object lives longer than the thread does. Its easy to miss seemingly simple things, believe me.

Comment: Yep, the class is part of the UI, so it doesn't get destroyed until the window is closed. Perfect - I love that it can just be passed as the parameter (facepalm `void *`)